# PHP Char causes null when querying a mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

There's a field in the database that contains single quotes (UNICODE: 8216 and 8217). An example of a value for this field:

ERROR: compilation failed for package **‘**robustbase**’**

When I try to retrieve it from my php script I get the field *q* as null:

```
$qrow = array("id" => $id,
"ip" => mysql_result($result, $_SESSION['row'], 1),
"q" => mysql_result($result, $_SESSION['row'], 2),
"time" => mysql_result($result, $_SESSION['row'], 3),
"ua" => mysql_result($result, $_SESSION['row'], 4),
"sess" => mysql_result($result, $_SESSION['row'], 5),
"links" => $alinks);
```

The other fields are perfectly fine.

**EDIT** I've tried to use the PHP function *htmlentities* before inserting to the database and the other function *html_entity_decode*  when retrieving but didn't work.

**EDIT2** I also tried to change the mysql collation to one more general: *ut8_general_ci* but didn't work..

**EDIT3** Adding slashes with *addslahes* before inserting doesn't work either.

**EDIT4** Also tried with *mysql_real_escape_string*... and nothing. I don't know what is happening.

**OBS** I am not using the magic quotes

Comment: ASCII has only 128 characters, extended ASCII has 256, affected by the encoding of your choice. What encoding are you actually using? It's not ASCII. Also, you should look into binding variables, I guess.

Comment: Those are Unicode code points.

Comment: For that field, in the database, I use latin1 collation

Comment: Is the latin1_spanish_ci. And the characters are those that are in bold in the example of my question

Comment: @AljoshaBre: you're right the code points that I described initially were from the unicode charset